# Is this the most efficient way to get data from database to datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb

> Im a beginner and hoping to know whats the most memory/processor efficient way to query. Am i placing the using and end using properly?. Is the New OleDbCommand still needed? Please comment your suggestions and tips to improve my code :)

```
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
 Dim dbProvider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
      Dim dbSource As String = ("Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\DBbms.accdb")
       con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
       

Using connection As New OleDbConnection(con.ConnectionString)
        Try

            Dim query As String = "Select * from Household"
            'cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)

            connection.Open()
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)


            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_database_access.htm

Comment: Thanks! Is it better to add a dataset then fill the table?

Comment: A `DataSet` can contain one or more `DataTable` object. Do you need to get multiple tables from the DB? No? Then use a `DataTable`.

Comment: So i should use Datatable, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your user interface code from your database code. If you want to show a message box in your `Catch` do it in the UI code.

You may want to make the connection string a class level variable so other database code can use it.

The Command is also included in the `Using` block. Note the comma at the end of the `Connection` line.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Try
        dt = GetHouseholdData()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
End Sub

Private HHConStr As String = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={Application.StartupPath}\DBbms.accdb"

Private Function GetHouseholdData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(HHConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from Household", con)
        con.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks will take note of that. Btw whats the use of Return dt?

Comment: All `Functions` should have a `Return` statement. The `Return dt` is sending the `DataTable` back to the calling code.

Comment: So i should add a new function form to the project instead of putting the command code to the form_load?

Comment: You can put the code from Button2_Click in the Form.Load. Then add the Function to the Form. Don't forget to add the connection string variable.

Comment: Thankyou so muchh! Last question tho im sorry . Is executereader better than dataadapter even i have to edit the data in the datagrid?

Comment: If you are planning on calling an Update on the DataAdapter, then do use a DataAdapter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Its actually for another button so ill still use this datareader